# Este codigo me retorna this diferente en el navegador y con node

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo este código, y estaba aprendiendo acerca de this en JavaScript, pero en el navegador me devuelve Jesus, mas en node me devuelve undefined, por qué?

```
this.nombre = 'Jesus'
function funcion(){
    return `${this.nombre}`
}
console.log(funcion())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` en JavaScript tiene un comportamiento diferente dependiendo del contexto. Puedes leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) para verlo más a profundidad.

En corto, cuando lo usas en el navegador, `this` se refiere al contexto global, y le estás asignando una propiedad llamada `nombre`.

En node, el contexto de `this` dentro de la función es la función en si misma, y no tiene una propiedad llamada nombre, por tanto su valor es `undefined`.